# modifying the bash prompt on mac

Tags: bash, osx-elcapitan

On my bash prompt, I would like to see just the name of the current directory followed by "$" in different colours.
So I used this code but when I have a long typed command, I see the cursor in different place than where the typing is taking place. How can this "hard to describe" problem be fixed? Thanks

```
PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]\W\[\e[m\]\[\e[1;31m\]\$\[\e[m\]'
```

Comment: check out this thread:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly Hope it helps.

Comment: This is BashFAQ #53: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: ...however, as a question more about end-user configuration than software development, it's not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a carriage-return after outputting the current directory,   I've done this for years and it works a treat, something like:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
    PS1="\[\e[0;36m\]\W\n\[\e[m\]\[\e[1;31m\]\$\[\e[m\]"
fi
```

You always have your current directory (no matter how long) *on top* of your `$` prompt.

I put other info up there as well like username, machine name and exact time and date. I colour them differently so they really stand out.  Helps if you have multiple sessions going on, on different machines with or without root(!) privileges (*have* to be root when deploying a complete rebuild).  And has saved the day many times when I need to know *when* I did something or other (ok, it's when that task ended - but still helps).

But most of all, it's great to know your current directory by simply looking at your command line prompt :) )

Don't know how other people work efficiently without it!